# Connect to SPFarm SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, claims-based-auth, ntlm

I want to create a function to connect to SPFarm SharePoint2010 with a login and password ,I knowed that it use NTLM authentification ,do I need credential connection ? 
is there any PowerShell commands or c# code samples .

And IT will be the same issues in SharePoint2013? because it use claim authetification.
 any ideas , best regards .

Comment: Try Get-SPFarm http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607966(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Get-SPFarm dont give us users infomations , I want to connect with login and password and to check if the logon is an admin farm or not .

Comment: Please specify clearly what you exacly want to achieve in your question.

Comment: create an authentification function(login,password) to verify if the user is a farm administrator or not

Comment: Get-SPProcessAccount give me system account with SecurityIdentifier ,but how can I verify the password ? thanks